# How to pass a register value into a include_role loop

Tags: loops, ansible, include, roles

I have an ansible playbook that is reading in a list of files, and setting a register for those values.  I want to then pass the list of files into an `include_role` task.  Below is my current code.

```
 - name: Get list of files
   command: "sh -c 'find playbooks/vars/files/*.yml'"
   register: find_files

 - include_vars:
     file: "{{ item }}"
   loop: "{{ find_files.stdout_lines }}"
   register: result

 - name: call role
   include_role:
     name: myRole
   loop: "{{ result.results }}"
```

When the playbook runs, its finds two files in the directory; `file1.yml` and `file2.yml`.  But when it runs through the `include_role` loop, its passes `file1.yml` twice and never passes `file2.yml`.  Trying to determine how I can ensure `file2.yml` gets passed to the role as well.

Comment: I don't believe looping over an `include_role:` (especially when the `name:` is a constant) will do anything except waste CPU; are you trying to pass different _variables_ to the role? Separately, `command: sh -c ""` is also known as [`shell:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/modules/shell_module.html)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the correct my issue by constructing an array and then feeding it into include_role and using the find module instead of shell.

```
 - name: Recursively find yml files
    find:
      paths: ~/vars
      recurse: yes
    register: find_files

  - name: Construct file array
    set_fact:
      file_arr: "{{ file_arr|default([]) + [file.path] }}"
    with_items: "{{ find_files.files }}"
    loop_control:
      loop_var: file

  - name: Topic Management
    include_role:
      name: kafkaTopicManagement
    vars:
      kafkaFiles: "{{ item }}"
    with_items: "{{ file_arr }}"
```

This now feeds the the files into include_role.